Vertically center circuitikz label/annotation (with zero depth)
When adding a label to circuitikz components, a strut is automatically inserted to ensure proper alignment between labels with/without ascenders and descenders. This is not always the desired behavior. For example, the C next to the capacitor below looks off-center. I added a "bare" node (without the strut) for comparison.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,.5) to [C, l=$C$] (0,-.5);
  \node at (1,0) {$C$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}


How can I use the natural height and depth of the label, without the size added by the strut?

Well, I'll look at it but I do not think it's the strut (this is quite old code...). If you add \usepackage{xpatch} \makeatletter \xpatchcmd{\pgf@circ@drawreglabels}{\strut}{}{}{\error} \makeatother  to kill the \strut there, nothing changes...

@Rmano Interesting.. But when you also add bipole label append style={anchor=west}, then it seems to work. Makes me wonder why the strut is there at all..

you can add it as an answer if you like. I have little time on my hands now, but I promise I'll look into it...

If you don't like where the label option puts things, you don't have to use it.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,.5) to [C, n=C1] (0,-.5);
  \node at ($(C1.south)!1.28!(C1.north)$) {$C$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}

